# How can a Java program read its own console output fully?

Tags: java, logging

First of all, I'm aware that if you want to start a process and get the console output from it, you can use for example this code:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process proc;
proc = builder.start();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream());
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

But what if I wanted to get the whole console output from the *currently running Java program*? Is it possible to read it without missing anything? I'm sure that the program for showing text in console uses `System.out.println()` in some places, in most it uses many instances of `java.util.logging.Logger`, and maybe some other methods somewhere else.

By the way, does the `Logger` class in the end simply use `System.out` to print text or does it use any other special methods for logging?

Anyway, can I somehow listen to all of these?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably u could search in memory instance of the class that does the out print to the console and redirect the text to your own Stream/Reader

Comment: I'm concerned why you want to do this, or what the context is where you think this is needed.  Most programmers would consider messing with the output streams a bad idea.  Frankly the answer below about redirecting output from the console is a better direction to take, but we likely need more context.

Comment: The `Logger` class does not use `System.out` normally.  The `Logger` class may, depending on configuration, use a `ConsoleHandler`, which sends output to `System.err`.  But the logger only delegates to handlers, it doesn't use any output method itself.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a complete solution to your problem. But it is one workaround that I have used somewhere.

You can redirect your program standard output to a file and from your program itself you can read that file as it is changed.

For a console based application, you can redirect your console output in a file using -

```
java -cp temp.jar test.Main >> program.log
```

program.log file will be created with all standard output messages even the program is still running.